# Websocket send() not working

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am making simple websocket demo ([ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws)) with expressjs

Server Side code

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
        , http = require('http')
        , express = require('express')
        , app = express();

app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(app.router);
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(2678);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('views/index.html');
});

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log("Connection Open");
    ws.on('message', function(e) {
        console.log(e); // Can't get message here
    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('stopping client interval');
    });
});
```

And my client side (Browser)

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2678?uid=123&token=abc123');
    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log('Connection Open');
        console.log('readyState:' + ws.readyState); // readyState:1
        ws.send("Test msg");
        console.log("sent!");
    };
```

Problem :

When I execute above code I can get message "Connection Open" Message on both side. But ws.send("Test msg") not working on client side. I can't emit data neither client side nor serverside. I found lots of question on Stack Overflow. But I can't found proper solution for that.
And When I close browser after 2-3 minute I got following message in server side.

```
Test msg
stopping client interval
```

I have refereed following links. But they are not working for me.

[Link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

[Link2](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md)